# Is OpenStreetMap data compatible with Google Map tiles layer?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, routing

I am building an android application to calculate and draw the shortest route for the user to go to a specified destination.

My application is using **osmdroid** library to render my map tiles.  I am using .mbtiles fomat generated from **google maps**. Now I want to add routing functionalities to let the user find the nearest way to the specific destination.

I found a the ***OpenStreetMap data*** that can be used with **GraphHopper** navigation library to achieve my task .

My question is that :

Is it compatible to use OpenStreetMap data with the Google Map tiles ?

Comment: In theory you can convert openstreetmap data to any projection, so, yes.

Comment: But Google Maps and OpenStreetMap may vary in detail/coverage depending where you are looking in the world.

Comment: OSM slippy tiles are designed to use the exact same x/y/z "coordinates" as Google Maps, so yes.

Comment: "hooper navigation library"? Are you talking about GraphHopper?

Comment: yes I mean GraphHopper. I edited it

Answer (score 1):

There should be no technical reason against that:
you can use raw OSM data and calculate a route between start and destination (defined by what???) and produce a routing graph line for that as an overlay.

Then choose whatever tiles you want and you are allowed to, and use those tiles as underlay.

But how will you handle situations where OSM data is uncomplete, outdated (should not of course!), or even more recent or more detailed in comparison to google tiles?

What is your personal reason against using OSM based tiles?

There are many map styles and some tile displaying frameworks for using / producing OSM based tiles. Or think about using OSM based vector maps.

Comment: I think there should be also no problem license-wise but the other way around (using Google Directions on OSM) is not allowed from Google.